# SharePoint 2010 approval workflow customization for stage level approvals?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint

Greetings!!!

I have the following scenario could you please help me to achieve this?
Using OOO approval workflow I need to approve a document/list item in two(or three) stages. Let me explain,
Whenever I create/upload a document it will go to the stage one approvers(minimum 2 approvers) if one of them from the stage one approves the document it should go to the stage two approval.

SharePoint 2010 has facility to add levels of approvers using 'Add new stage' button. But the issue is this works only if all the approvers from the stage one approve the document then it is coming for the stage two for approval. In my case if anyone from the stage one approves it should flow to the stage two for approval.
I tried to customizing the workflow using SPD 2010, but I am unable to achieve the same. Could you please help me out?
Let me know if you need more information.

Thanks,
Royal.

Answer (score 0):

you have to choose between serial approval and parallel approval.
by default serial approval is selected but if you choose parallel then any of them can approve.